Tailwind change text color in all input elements
So I have the following code in several places across the app:
<label className="input text-neutral-content">
   Name
   <input type="text" className="grow text-base-content"/>
</label>

I know that the idea behind tailwind is inline styling but is there a way to define the text color of label and input globally so I don't have to repeat the text-neutral-content and text-base-content in each and every input field?

Yes Sure.
in your global.css file you can your default styles like this:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

    @layer base {
      h1 {
        @apply text-2xl;
      }
      h2 {
        @apply text-xl;
      }
    
      input {
       @apply text-base-content
      }
      /* ... */
    }

You can read more here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer

There are two ways to solve this problem:
1. Using tailwind.config.js config:
Declare colors:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "ligth-coffee": "#C89F94"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Usage:
<p class="text-ligth-coffee">text color</p>

2. Custom class in global.css:
Custom class pxh-text-red:
.pxh-text-red {
    @apply red;
}

Usage:
<p class="pxh-text-red">text color</p>


You can use '@apply' to append your class to an existing Tailwind class. You can add it in your CSS file, something like this:
.label {
    @apply input text-neutral-content;
}

